# How to configure External tool in Eclipse to run a jar file and load other class files?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, external-tools

In Eclipse Indigo (on Mac OSX), I have a project 'Test'. In this project I have a package 'test1'.  In this package, I have a class Test.java.

In short the file structure is:  Test/src/Test.java and
                                   Test/bin/Test.class

I have a library **mylib.jar** in lib folder.

I also have a data file named **info.dat**. In info.dat, there's information about which class to load. For example, in info.dat, I specified: **class=Test**
then, when I run:

```
$  java -jar lib/mylib.jar info.dat  

(NOTE: this works if I run this command in terminal and have class file in the same folder with info.dat)
```

the main function in mylib.jar will load Test.class.

I'm using **External Tools** to achieve this. Here is my External tool setup:

```
Location: /usr/bin/java
Working Location: /path/to/Test_folder
Argument: -cp . -jar lib/mylib.jar bin/test1/info.dat
```

However, when I try to run, I get this error:

```
LOADING INFO FROM FILE bin/test1/info.dat
=> Current directory=[not include because not important]
=> Full pathname=[not include because not important]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
```

I also tried to change **class=test.Test** in info.dat but got a similar error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test1.Test
```

The result shows that the info.dat was loaded ok, but the path to class file was not correct. How should I configure the external tool to do what I need? Can someone please give me some instruction?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It was an easy solution with Run Configuration. I just need to pick the main class from mylib.jar in Java Application and put info.dat in the argument field.

Sorry for wasting the resource here.